# Finding odd one out from the following sequence

Tags: number-sequence

I was trying to find odd one out from the sequence as follows -

$−3,9,41,113,262,577$

I took the difference of the consecutive terms -

$12,32,72,149,315$

I still could not find any pattern in order to find odd one out.

Any other method to find the odd one out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the odd one out is

> 262

It should be

> 265

Because

> The general solution is T(n+1) = T(n) * 2 + 8 * (n + 1) - 1

Detailed list:

> -3 * 2 + 15 = 9
>  9 * 2 + 23 = 41
>  41 * 2 + 31 = 113
>  113 * 2 + 39 = 265
>  265 * 2 + 47 = 577

Comment: I am not sure how to add a spoiler block, I wanted to list the pattern for all the numbers

Comment: For future reference, new lines can be added to a spoiler by including two spaces at the end of the line.